# How create the line that intersects the medians of the groups using R:ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data with some dynamic measurements.

```
datadim=structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), dim1 = c(60L, 69L, 60L, 
63L, 61L, 68L, 68L, 69L, 66L, 60L, 69L, 62L, 60L, 60L, 70L, 67L, 
68L, 70L, 66L), dim2 = c(70L, 61L, 61L, 66L, 65L, 69L, 70L, 70L, 
66L, 69L, 61L, 66L, 66L, 65L, 62L, 68L, 61L, 63L, 61L), dim3 = c(63L, 
62L, 66L, 62L, 69L, 60L, 62L, 68L, 64L, 61L, 68L, 63L, 65L, 63L, 
64L, 62L, 69L, 62L, 63L), dim4 = c(68L, 69L, 67L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 
70L, 70L, 62L, 64L, 61L, 69L, 66L, 61L, 68L, 66L, 66L, 67L, 64L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
```

I want create boxplots for this, with line for compare median for my focus group (`group` column).
I just use simple `boxplot(datadim)` but i didn't get needed line. I just get such.
[image]

I don't want such plots. I need plots like i created in paint
[image]
Where blue color is first group and red color is second group. I also signed in what places which descriptive statistics are displayed(95% confidence interval,max,min,median). Inside each group, for example the first, we see a blue line that passes through the median of each dimension, and similarly, inside the second group, the red line passes along the median of each dimension. But `boxplot` doesn't create it.
How using `boxplot` or `ggplot2` get plots like i provided in my second picture  where there is a line by medians for each group separately (blue and red lines)?

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57043433/how-to-connect-the-median-values-of-a-boxplot-with-multiple-groups-using-lines-i/57044728)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stat_summary` in `ggplot`. To do this, you first need to convert your data to long format (here using `tidyr::pivot_longer()` and convert the group to a factor:

```
library(tidyr)
datadim.lng <- datadim %>% pivot_longer(-group,names_to="dim", values_to = "value")

datadim.lng$group <- as.factor(datadim.lng$group)
```

Then run the `ggplot` code:

```
ggplot(datadim.lng, aes(x = dim, y = value, fill = group)) + 
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 0.85), width = 0.8) +
  theme_classic() +
  stat_summary(
    fun = median,
    geom = 'line',
    aes(group = group, color = group),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.85) 
  )
```

Which gives:

[image]

If you want to change the color of the line, per your example:

```
ggplot(datadim.lng, aes(x = dim, y = value, fill = group)) + 
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 0.85), width = 0.8) +
  theme_classic() +
  stat_summary(
    fun = median,
    geom = 'line',
    aes(group = group, color = group),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.85) 
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))
```

Which gives:
[image]